# Comparar textos de itens de um recyclerview

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Gostaria de saber como fazer para comparar textos de itens de um recyclerView no android.

**E caso os textos forem iguais**, tornar o texto do item de baixo **GONE**.

```
public void pegarTexto (){

    TextView um =  (TextView) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(mAdapter.getItemId(-1)).itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomePais);
    TextView dois = (TextView) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(mAdapter.getItemId(0)).itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomePais);

    String pais1 = um.toString();
    String pais2 = dois.toString();

    if (pais1 == pais2){

        dois.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

**Segue imagens do problema.**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima os itens 2 e 3 tem o mesmo nome do item 1, portando eles ficariam invisiveis (GONE).

**Na imagem abaixo mostro como deveria ficar.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na recyclerview no método onBindViewHolder, faça a comparação com o anterior, só faça um tratamento para quando for a primeira posição. Se for igual você coloca o setVisibility do item que possui o texto para GONE

Comment: A duvida é realmente como fazer essa comparação, e como infentificar o item anterior.

Comment: if(position > 0){

            if(mList.get(position - 1).equals(holder.tvDate.getText().toString().trim())){
            
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

Comment: não sei como você esta trabalhando, então fiz um exemplo com uma lista de string

Answer (score 0):

`==` Testa as referências dos dois objetos (se é o mesmo objeto na memória) .

`.equals()` Testa se os valores dos objetos são iguais (se são objetos diferentes na memória, porém com os mesmos valores/conteúdo).

Portanto, use o `.equals()` para comparar.

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/4916458